# class constants and file imports for java

Tags: java

I'm pretty much trying to use a class constant to declare as a file but get an error.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class BabyNames {
   public static final Scanner NAME=new Scanner(new File("names.txt")); //specifically this part 
   public static final int YEAR=1900;                                   //generates the error
   public static final int LS=11;
   public static final int WIDTH=50;
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
      intro();
      personName();
      graph();
   }

// Error contained:
// BabyNames.java:6: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or
// declared to be thrown                 
//   public static final Scanner NAME=new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));
                                ^
//1 error
```

this is not all of the program but dont think the rest is required.
sorry if my method of asking was funky, first time. thanks much.

Comment: The `Scanner` constructor throws a checked exception, which must be caught.  You could put this logic in a static helper method, or a static initializer block.

Comment: I don't think your method of asking is funky. Instead, it's very good for a first time question. You showed the relevant code and the exception and it was very clear what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you can use a static initializer block to set your staic final `Scanner` variable. Inside the initializer block you can use try/catch:

```
public static final Scanner NAME; 

static {
  // Be sure scanner is initialized even in the case of an exception
  Scanner scanner = null;

  try {
    new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  NAME = scanner;
}
```

BUT: It is bad style to hold an instance of a class like `Scanner` as a static constant. A Scanner is a one way object. You are about to consume the file content and that's it. It doesn't make sense to hold such an object as a constant and much less if it is `public`. 
A static variable will be intialized as soon as the class is loaded and lives as long as your program. In most cases this is not what you want.

A better approach would be to make it an instance variable and initilize it in the constructor. And make it private to the class. You can hold the file name as a constant and create the constructor to accept any file name. The methods `intro()`, `personName()` and `graph()` can be made instance methods, too.

```
public class BabyNames {
  public static final String NAMES_FILE_NAME = "names.txt";

  public static final int YEAR=1900;                                   
  public static final int LS=11;
  public static final int WIDTH=50;

  private final Scanner name; 

  public BabyNames(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    name = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    BabyNames babyNames = new BabyNames(NAMES_FILE_NAME);
    babyNames.intro();
    babyNames.personName();
    babyNames.graph();
  }

  public void graph() {
    // ...    
  }

  public void personName() {
    // ...    
  }

  public void intro() {
    // ...    
  }

  // ...
}
```

As a consequence the Scanner variable is only known to the `BabyNames` class  and lives as long as the particular `BabyNames` instance. This is more modular, better to maintain and easier to test. E.g. you can write a unit test and initialize your class with a test file.

Answer (score 0):

You need a try catch around that code.

That's what "must be caught or declared to be thrown" means.

Read this : [doc oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html)

Comment: thanks much, would i still need the throws FileNotFoundException, or not needed now that i have the try/catch?

Comment: naaa, the catch will take care of that exception.

Comment: ok, so im getting these errors now, 1 is still the same. BabyNames.java:6: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
   public static final Scanner NAME=new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));
                                    ^
BabyNames.java:15: error: exception FileNotFoundException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
      }catch(FileNotFoundException e){

Comment: i did make it to were it try/catches in perhaps an illegal spot, try{
         intro();
         personName();
         graph();
      }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
      }  dont know if i did that properly, and how do i make a new line in this chat window lmao.

Comment: then why don't you just declare your static class member "public static Scanner NAME;" THEN you initialize that variable in the main function try{
   NAME=new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));
}catch(Exception e){
}
 not a class constant but still a public class member.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of Exception :
1) checked Exception: those should be handle at compile time (by using try,catch,throws)
2) unchecked Exception: No compiler error for these exception but at run time exception may occurs.

Your case is first one FileNotFoundException is checked exception so either you have to write that line inside try catch block or you have to use keyword  throws. to pass exception handling to calling method.